# Do something after DataGrid finished loading with async ItemsSource?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that loads a large number of items, so I set the `ItemsSource` to `IsAsync=True`.

```
 <DataGrid Name="OrdersGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Orders, IsAsync=True}" />
```

Everything seems to work fine except for changing the `NewItemPlaceHolderPosition` in my `UserControl` subclass constructor.

```
((IEditableCollectionView)OrdersGrid.Items).NewItemPlaceholderPosition = NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning;
```

I assume that this crashes because you can't set it for an empty grid, which is what I have before the async `ItemsSource` binds.

So where should I put the above line to make sure the `DataGrid` is loaded before I attempt to change the `NewItemPlaceholderPosition`? I need something like "DataGridFinishedLoading" but I don't know what is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Binding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.notifyontargetupdated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what you are looking for.

Set **`NotifyOnTargetUpdated`** to **`true`** on your binding and hook handler which needs to be invoked when Target *(DataGrid in your case)* is updated.

You can check with **`args.Property`** that which binding has been notified.

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid Name="OrdersGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Orders, IsAsync=True,
                                NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
          TargetUpdated="DataGrid_TargetUpdated"/>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void DataGrid_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Property == DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty)
    {
        ((IEditableCollectionView)OrdersGrid.Items).NewItemPlaceholderPosition = 
                                   NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the `Status` of the `ItemContainerGenerator` if it finished generating and also if the `Items` count is `0`.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var datagrid = new DataGrid();
    datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGeneratorOnStatusChanged;
}

private void ItemContainerGeneratorOnStatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dataGrid == null) return;
    if (dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
       ((IEditableCollectionView)OrdersGrid.Items).NewItemPlaceholderPosition = NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning;
    }
}
```